# Maven build is very slow without -Xdebug option

Tags: java, maven

I have run into a very strange issue with Maven.

It seems that removing the -Xdebug option from my MAVEN_OPTS environment variable significantly slows down the build process. Let's see some benchmark results:

MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xmx4096m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

2-3 minutes.

MAVEN_OPTS=-Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xmx4096m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

At least 7 minutes.

This has been checked 3 times, so it is sure that the removal of -Xdebug causes the slowness. Do you know what could cause this?

I'am doing an mvn clean install on a maven project that consists of 7 modules.

I'm using:

- Windows 7
- Apache Maven 3.3.9
- Java version: 1.8.0_60

Comment: Wait, what? Adding `-Xdebug`, so having a lot more logs and more IO, makes the build go _faster_?

Comment: Yes. It was there in my config for a long time, but now I wanted to remove it and saw that the build just became very slow.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to run Maven?

Comment: Just mvn clean install. Actually, now it seems that if I also remove -Djava.compiler=NONE and -Xnoagent, then the build is back to normal speed :O

Comment: Based on what I read `WARNING:  When running with -Xdebug the JVM is not running at its full speed. Thus, the option should not be used for applications when running in production environments.` so it's not astonishing ...I would expect that ` -Djava.compiler=NONE` is the problem and performance issue....cause you turn off the JIT Compiler...

Comment: I also encounter the same problem, Can anybody tell me why?